# view or convert MDI file

Tags: files, file-format, format-conversion

I have some insurance files that I need to be able to view, but they are in the MDI format I can't get them to work at all in Ubuntu. 
I've searched the entire forum and I've even installed Microsoft office 2003 & 2007 through Wine, but it still doesn't work correctly.

The only solutions posted in the forum have suggested getting an MDI to pdf converter or installing MS office.  I haven't gotten any of this to work.

How can I view or convert MDI files?

Answer (score 2):

File format descriptions of this say something like: """The MDI is a a high resolution, tag-based graphics format. MDI files are only supported by the Microsoft Office 2003 version (NOT supported in Office 2007) of Microsoft Office Document Imaging. If you are going to share files with people who are using Office Document Imaging 2002, or another document imaging program, save your files in TIFF format for compatibility."""

So apparently even Microsoft doesn't support this format anymore...  Maybe you can tell the insurance company that you don't have that antique MS Office version (anymore)?  (And in the mean time, use Document Viewer as "moberley" suggests.)

Comment: For your information previously in my system having windows MDI is supported in Microsoft office 2007.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have access to any Microsoft Document Imaging (MDI) files to test out on my system, but I figured I'd see if I could get the Bugysoft MDI2PDF converter (a Windows program) to run with Wine. I got some errors from the installer and was not able to get the program to start up.

However, MDI2PDF did include a example single page MDI file which I was able to open in the Gnome Document Viewer (on Ubuntu 10.04). I did have to manually select the Document Viewer application to open the file because Ubuntu did not associate the .mdi extension.

Comment: Microsoft also have a conversion tool that will convert MDI files to TIFF: https://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=30328 It might work under Wine....

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a lot of poor reviews for Bugysoft MDI2PDF.

A lot of people seem to recommend [PrimoPDF](http://www.primopdf.com) which doesn't explicitly advertise MDI conversion but its users do. It also does more than MDI2PDF. But does it work on Wine? Well I'll leave that to you to find out.